# Specify paths to actions in aspx pages MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, path, action

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC application. On my master page, I have a form that I need to submit to another action. Below is the relevant code:

```
<form id="form1" action="/Stock/PerformSearch" method="post" runat="server">
//some other stuff          
</form>
```

As you can see, when I submit the form I want to go to the "PerformSearch" action in the "Stock" controller. This works fine on my local machine hosting. But when I try to publish the site on the server, MVC doesn't recognize this path anymore. My question is how should I specify the paths to actions in aspx pages such that it will work both locally and on live. I know that I can use the "using Html.BeginForm" and that will solve the problem, but I really don't want to use it for other reasons and also, I always need to specify paths to actions in many other tags other that form tag.

By the way, changing the path to "http://cse454db.cs.washington.edu/BestBet/Stock/PerformSearch"

will make it run on the server since the given path is the exact path for where the application will live (including the virtual directory) but I know this is not the perfect solution since I have to keep changing the path back and forth whenever running it locally or live. Also, I have the same problems in specifying the paths to actions in javascript files. I know there should be an easy solution for it, but I have been looking and couldn't find anything so any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC. You should use HTML helpers and never ever put a `runat="server"` tag in an ASP.NET MVC view. So your form could look like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("PerformSearch", "Stock")) { %>
    //some other stuff
<% } %>
```

This will take care of generating the proper form tag.

Comment: how about paths in JavaScript files?? how do I specify the path??

Comment: It depends on what paths you are talking about and how are you handling them in your javascript.

Comment: I'm talking about the ajax calls, the paths that you put in the "url:" field

Comment: It depends. If you use links `Html.ActionLink` in your page which will generate proper urls, you could progressively enhance those links with jquery and ajaxify them: `$('a#someLink').click(function() { $.get(this.href, function(result) {  }); return false; });`. Notice how I am using the link href to perform my ajax call. In this case you don't need to hardcode urls in your javascript files. Same stands true for forms. If you don't have a corresponding link you could always generate a global javascript variable: `var url = '<%= Url.Action("foo") %>';` which you would use in your js file.